# Require Simplification On Linq To Assign Values To Dynamic Class Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Thanks in advance. I have got required details but i would like to simplify the code. I have showed my code below. Kindly have a look.

```
    public class EmployeeInfo()
    {
        public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
        public string MiddleName {get;set;}
    }

    public class SalaryDetails()
    {
        public string CreatedFirstName {get;set;}
        public string CreatedLastName {get;set;}
        public string CreatedMiddleName {get;set;}
        public string UpdatedFirstName {get;set;}
        public string UpdatedLastName {get;set;}
        public string UpdatedMiddleName {get;set;}
        public int CreatedBy {get;set;}
        public int UpdatedBy {get;set;}
        public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
    }


var lstSalary = (from i in _context.SalaryDetails where i.employeeId=EmployeeId select i).ToList()  

lstSalary.ForEach(item =>
            {

List<int> Employeeids=new List<int>(new []{1,2,3,4,5,6});

List<EmployeeInfo> lst = (
                    from e in _context.Employee
                    where Employeeids.Contains(e.Eid)
                    select new EmployeeInfo
                    {
                        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                        FirstName = e.FirstName,
                        LastName = e.LastName,
                        MiddleName = e.MiddleName
                    }).ToList();

    //Need to simplify this below code to set values
item.CreatedFirstName =
    lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy).FirstName;
item.CreatedLastName =
    lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy).LastName;
item.CreatedMiddleName =
    lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy).MiddleName;

if (item.UpdatedBy.HasValue)
{
    item.UpdatedFirstName =
        lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.UpdatedBy).FirstName;
    item.UpdatedLastName =
        lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.UpdatedBy).LastName;
    item.UpdatedPersonMiddleName =
        lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.UpdatedBy).MiddleName;
}

}
```

I need to simplify to set createdby and updatedby employee name, could anyone give some solution or tips.

Comment: Why not store `lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy)` in a variable and then assign the values..?

Comment: i want to set FirstName to CreatedFirstName from lst object. so i am trying to do that way

Comment: I don't see how that invalidates my comment. You're searching for the same employee every time. Get the employee once and then copy the properties over.

Comment: We can store the list lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy) to variable and assign the values, can we do any other ways?

Comment: What's the problem with a variable?

Comment: By seeing the code, It's sloppy. So i want to simplify

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can see doing this is by using reflection

```
public static void SetSalaryDetails(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo, SalaryDetails salaryDetails, string prefix)
{
   foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(EmployeeInfo).GetProperties())
   {
       if (propertyInfo.Name.Contains("Name"))
       {
            typeof(SalaryDetails)
                .GetProperty(prefix + propertyInfo.Name)
                .SetValue(salaryDetails,
                    propertyInfo.GetValue(employeeInfo));
       }
   }
}
```

this method will map the fields from EmployeeInfo, which contain "Name" in their field names, to the fields in SalaryDetails that have the name prefix + FieldName from EmployeeInfo

Your code would become

```
List<EmployeeInfo> lst = (
                    from e in _context.Employee
                    where Employeeids.Contains(e.Eid)
                    select new EmployeeInfo
                    {
                        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                        FirstName = e.FirstName,
                        LastName = e.LastName,
                        MiddleName = e.MiddleName
                    }).ToList();

    //Need to simplify this below code to set values
SetSalaryDetails(lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy), item, "Created");

if (item.UpdatedBy.HasValue)
{
    SetSalaryDetails(lst.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == item.CreatedBy), item, "Updated");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.